# How to console.log() while in Chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

Is there a way to do a console.log('something') in chrome console and have it display a value in chrome console? When I run

```
console.log('something')
```

I get undefined. I am trying to write a function into the console and would like it to spit some things out as it runs. Any help would be awesome!

Example:

I paste this into the chrome console window:

```
    function test(){
      console.log('hi');
    }
```

then run:

```
test()
```

and I get:

```
undefined
```

[image]

Comment: `console.log('something')` should log 'something'. what's your function? put it in your question.

Comment: It should log "something" and then also say "undefined" (because that is the return value of `console.log`. You can just type `something` into the console, and it will print that value.

Comment: Let me get a quick sample for you.

Comment: You get undefined, because your function returns undefined/nothing. But it should also be logging "hi". Doesn't it? (It does for me on Firefox)

Comment: In chrome it only returns undefined. If there is another way I would very interested in it.

Comment: "In chrome it only returns undefined" --- show us a screenshot

Comment: In the chrome console I'm getting `hi` then `undefined`. With the exact code you have above.

Comment: What version of chrome are you on?